# Get dnsmasq to respond with the local dynamic IP address

Tags: docker, dnsmasq

We're using dnsmasq on our Macs for local development to send all traffic for *.dev to 127.0.0.1.  We're working on moving to Docker for local dev, but still need to support running MySQL on the Macs outside of Docker for now.

I'm trying to determine of there is a way to get dnsmasq to respond with the local IP address of the Mac when queries are issued for things like mysql.dev.  This IP address will change based on which network the Macs are connected to, including when they work from home or on the road.  The 127.0.0.1 address won't work for our situation.

If dnsmasq isn't the right or best choice, I'm open to others or even using the HOSTS file, if there's a way.

Any ideas?